# Linking OTF font with CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm building a site locally and trying to link an OTF typeface on my site but I can't seem to get it to display in the browser. After inspecting the console, I can see that the fonts aren't being found, though I'm linking to the file path correctly.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image: console]

```
@font-face {
   font-family: ObjectSans;
   src: url("assets/fonts/ObjectSans-Heavy.otf") format("opentype");
   font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
   font-family: ObjectSans;
   src: url("assets/fonts/ObjectSans-Regular.otf") format("opentype");
   font-weight: normal;
}

h1 {
   font-family: ObjectSans;
   font-size: 3.8rem;
   font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
   font-family: ObjectSans;
   font-size:2.4rem;
   font-weight: bold;
}   

body {
   font-family: ObjectSans;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-size: 2rem;
   color: #FFF;
   background: rgb(0,0,0);
   background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(11,11,11,1) 50%, rgba(15,15,15,1) 100%);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height: 100%;
   background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Let's start with: what do your dev tools console and network tab say? Do your fonts even get loaded? Do you see 404s? 500s? CORS errors? etc. For that matter: does your _css file_ even load? Does your HTML have the correct `<link>` markup? And most importantly: don't reply with the answers, [update your post so it has all the details](/help/how-to-ask) instead.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. I have updated the question with what I've found in the console.

Comment: The console is literally telling you what's wrong, you don't need our help yet.

Comment: Got it working, thank you for your help. Just to clarify, I thought that you had to define the start of the file path at the root of the directory where the index file is, not starting at C:

Comment: What? The `src` attribute takes a **URL**, not a file path. It has to be the URL that the browser can get the font file at, so it doesn't matter where on your drive(s) those files live, it's _purely_ based on where you _server_ puts them relative to the CSS file that is loading them as part of servicing page requests